# How to recover corrupt git repository?

Tags: git

My computer turned off unexpectedly and it now seems all git commands result to this:

> error: object file
>   .git/objects/fd/5cdc549bf9104990c5933c4c5bfddb6ba7fed8 is empty
>       error: object file .git/objects/fd/5cdc549bf9104990c5933c4c5bfddb6ba7fed8 is empty
>       fatal: loose object fd5cdc549bf9104990c5933c4c5bfddb6ba7fed8 (stored in .git/objects/fd/5cdc549bf9104990c5933c4c5bfddb6ba7fed8) is
>   corrupt

As a result , I am getting some of the files blank.

Comment: this is not an git issue, but an FS issue.

Comment: ...and this is why it's important to have a good backup strategy - you do have backups, I hope ?

Comment: You have a backup, right? If you have an upstream repo, you can simply reclone (loosing the work since the last `git push`, of course). Otherwise, there is little you can do: You are missing some data, and all the trees/commits that depend on that data are corrupt as a consequence. Of course, you might try to narrow down which objects are actually corrupt, and which other objects depend on those corrupt objects, in an attempt to recover all the data that's still recoverable. But I guess, that might be difficult.

Comment: try to ask on the git mailing list, maybe someone can hack a solution https://git-scm.com/community

Comment: just out of curiosity, if you do a git fsck, does it attempt to fix anything?

Comment: Git got messed seriously because just about any command results to the error message.